# Fetch Ids of possible users having maximum followers

Tags: c#, twitter

How to fetch Ids of possible users having maximum followers in Twitter ?

Comment: I did not find any documentation for this in twitter developer .

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `GET followers/ids` to find the followers are thereby you can get the maximum users of the users.

`GET followers/ids` :Returns a cursored collection of user IDs for every user following the specified user.

Example Request

```
GET
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=sitestreams&count=5000
```

[Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)